# How to stop pending ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to stop pending ajax requests when a certain action happen on a LeafletJS map. Here is exactly what I am doing, I have a map ( that uses LeafletJS ) which queries a WMS service, when a user pan, zoom, or query a new layer, the previously queued ajax requests continue to wait for a response.

The idea is to process only the requests that would serve the current map view criteria and cancel everything else. The reason I am trying to achieve this is to improve the performance and the speed of rendering of the current action and ignore all previous actions.

I feel like this is more of a Javascript question than a leafletJS specific question so I looked into *abort()* but i am not sure how to apply it with LeafletJS

Edited:
Here is the code I currently have to query the WMS service ( The service is private )

```
$scope.makeWMSLayer = function (layerInfo) {

            if (layerInfo == null)
                return false;

            var uri = apiUrl+"/WMSService/";
            var options = {
                layers: layerInfo.Name,
                maxZoom: layerInfo.maxZoom || 20,
                minZoom: layerInfo.minZoom || 11 ,
                format: 'image/jpeg',
                transparent: true
            };
            var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(uri, options);

            layer.on({
                load: function () { self.layersLoading[layerInfo.Name] = false; digest(); },
                loading: function () { self.layersLoading[layerInfo.Name] = true; digest(); }
            });

/*keep current active layer inside a $rootScope variable*/
            $rootScope.activeLayer = layer;

            return layer;
        };
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have now?

Comment: I updated my question with the function that creates all the ajax requests. 12 to 15 requests occur when a new layer is requested!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery for getting JSON data, you should use `$.ajax` instead of others (like `$.getJSON` etc.), and store it as a value.

Like

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({ [...] }, [...]);
```

then just abort it:

```
jqXHR.abort();
```

EDIT:

TileLayer does not provide any ajax requests.
It's simply assigning a "src" attribute for tiles.

Unless you want to implement your own asynchronous (pre)loading by e.g. extending TileLayer, `window.stop()` is your only go.

Comment: OP stated: I feel like this is more of a Javascript question than a leafletJS specific question so I looked into abort() but i am not sure how to apply it with LeafletJS

Comment: is there a leaflet way of doing this? LeafletJS is responsible of initiating all ajax requests, and I am not sure how to access that!

Comment: You need to provide your geojson initialization. There is no inbult ajax facility in leafletjs.

Comment: @Victor I am not using tileLayer.geojson, I am using tileLayer.wms